i want to show a available banking payment related application which is installed in device in Flutter
In My App I have one Payment Which i show available payment related application show how i can show this application in flutter.
Future<void> _getPaymentApps() async {
    try {
      final List<dynamic> apps = await platform.invokeMethod('getPaymentApps');
      setState(() {
        _paymentApps = List<String>.from(apps);
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Failed to get payment apps: '${e.message}'.");
    }
  }

I use this code for method channel but it not work
And Create a chanel in Native code
private static final String CHANNEL = "com.example.payment_gateways/paymentApps";

    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
                .setMethodCallHandler(
                        new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
                                if (call.method.equals("getPaymentApps")) {
                                    List<String> paymentApps = getPaymentApps();
                                    result.success(paymentApps);
                                } else {
                                    result.notImplemented();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
    }

    private List<String> getPaymentApps() {
        List<String> paymentApps = new ArrayList<>();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL);
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfoList) {
            paymentApps.add(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
        }
        return paymentApps;
    }


First : add this permission in AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>

Second : add this in your MainActivity.kt
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "com.example.payment_gateways/paymentApps"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(
            flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,
            CHANNEL
        ).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "getPaymentApps") {
                result.success(getPaymentApps())
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getPaymentApps(): List<String> {
        val paymentApps = listOf(
            "com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user", // this is for Google Pay
            "com.phonepe.app", //this is for  PhonePe
            "net.one97.paytm", // this is for Paytm 
            // You can add other payment app package names
        )
        val installedPaymentApps = mutableListOf<String>()
        val packageManager = packageManager
        val packages = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)

        for (app in paymentApps) {
            try {
                packageManager.getPackageInfo(app, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)
                installedPaymentApps.add(app)
            } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
                // App is not installed
            }
        }

        return installedPaymentApps
    }
}

Third : Create a dart file and add this
    class PaymentAppChecker {
  static const platform = MethodChannel('com.example.payment_gateways/paymentApps');

  static Future<List<String>> getPaymentApps() async {
    try {
      final List<String>? installedApps = await platform.invokeListMethod<String>('getPaymentApps');
      return installedApps ?? [];
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Failed to get installed payment apps: '${e.message}'.");
      return [];
    }
  }
}

That's it you can use getPaymentApps for getting the payment related app.

In my app I Want to add payment method through the gpay,phonepa & paytm  so any Idea about it  @Himanshu Bora  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78800955/in-flutter-application-open-google-pay-in-device-application-and-return-the-paym]

Check here @Nim https://stackoverflow.com/a/78803894/16625547
