In Flutter Application Open google pay in device application and return the payment status
In My Application i want to show a one Google pay Button when the user click on this button i want to pass the whom to pay upi id redirect on google pay application transction page and after the payment sucessfully then redirect on my application and show the payment status whatever it sucess or fail,cancle etc.
For the Open the google pay i  use Url luncher code But it does not work it not Open direct Google pay
so Give any other solutions for payment integration in google pay,phonepe,paytm in flutter ..

if you have only one purpose to integrate payment then you can use Razorpay Payment. razorpay_flutter . It includes everything from payment apps to card to UPI payments. If you need any other help regarding razorpay do let me know.

razorpay can not Provide a customize Ui integration in flutter sdk .i already integrate razorpay but it can not give a customize checkout ui how i can customize razorpay checkout ui ? @Himanshu Bora

You can create your custom UI and then use the APIs given by razorpay.
Here is  the postman collection for the Razorpay APIs : https://www.postman.com/razorpaydev/razorpay-public-workspace/documentation/mfu7vaw/razorpay-apis

Thank You but I have no idea about the Razorpay api . and i have question when i use card through payment after filling card details i saw in other application open a otp screen . so i can Open that otp screen and all razorpay apii call using the http ? @Himanshu Bora

pay package can help you
First create dart file (payment_config.dart) inside lib folder that will hold the payment configuration details

You can get those payment configuration here:
https://github.com/google-pay/flutter-plugin/blob/main/pay/example/lib/payment_configurations.dart
let’s define the Google Pay button widget
var googlePayButton = GooglePayButton(
  paymentConfiguration: PaymentConfiguration.fromJsonString(
      defaultGooglePayConfigString),
  paymentItems: [PaymentItem(
    label: 'Total',
    amount: '0.01',
    status: PaymentItemStatus.final_price,
  )],
  type: GooglePayButtonType.pay,
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
  onPaymentResult: onGooglePayResult,
  loadingIndicator: const Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  ),
),

Now you can use this widget anywhere you want and it will make the payment.
Finally you need a google pay business account in google pay console to make real payments.

using this code you redirect on google pay device application and then pay the money? @Osama Ali

Yes it will redirect you to google pay app. In config file don't forget to  replace "gateway": "example" and "gatewayMerchantId": "gatewayMerchantId" with your actual payment gateway details and change "environment": "TEST" to "PRODUCTION" for production.

i use this string but it can not redirect in Googlepay Application
{   "provider": "google_pay",   "data": {     "environment": "TEST",     "apiVersion": 2,     "apiVersionMinor": 0,     "allowedPaymentMethods": [       {         "type": "CARD",         "tokenizationSpecification": {           "type": "PAYMENT_GATEWAY",           "parameters": {             "gateway": "example",             "gatewayMerchantId": "gatewayMerchantId"           }         },

"parameters": {           "allowedCardNetworks": ["VISA", "MASTERCARD"],           "allowedAuthMethods": ["PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"],           "billingAddressRequired": true,         }       }     ],     "merchantInfo": {       "merchantId": "01234567890123456789",       "merchantName": "Example Merchant Name"     },     "transactionInfo": {       "countryCode": "US",       "currencyCode": "USD"     }   }
using this code i click on pay button open card details Form in model sheer @Osama Ali
